# Zend Framework 2: Showing active state of Navigation for child route when using multiple Navigations

Tags: php, zend-framework2

## Introduction

I am working on a very large site that has two navigation menus per page. The first is a global navigation that links to sections of the website and the second is a section-level navigation for the selected item in the global navigation menu.

For the sake of efficiency, we decided that it would be unwise to always load the entire site navigation structure within the `Navigation` service. Instead, we opted to always load the global navigation structure but then use a separate `Navigation` that is generated based on the loaded section.

## Configuration

The global `Navigation` looks like this:

```
array(
    array(
        'type' => 'mvc',
        'label' => 'Section 1',
        'route' => 'section1'
    ),
    array(
        'type' => 'mvc',
        'label' => 'Section 2',
        'route' => 'section2'
    ),
    array(
        'type' => 'mvc',
        'label' => 'Section 3',
        'route' => 'section3'
    )
)
```

and the dynamically loaded section-level `Navigation` looks like this:

```
array(
    array(
        'type' => 'uri',
        'label' => 'Group 1',
        'pages' => array(
            array(
                'type' => 'mvc',
                'label' => 'Page 1',
                'route' => 'section1/page1'
            ),
            array(
                'type' => 'mvc',
                'label' => 'Page 2',
                'route' => 'section1/page2'
            ),
            array(
                'type' => 'mvc',
                'label' => 'Page 3',
                'route' => 'section1/page3'
            ),
        )
    )
    // ... more groups
)
```

## Problem

The problem is that the global `Navigation` only has an active item when the high-level route is currently being requested (e.g. `section1`). As soon as the user navigates to another page within the section (e.g. `section1/page1`), the global `Navigation` no longer has an active item.

## What was tried

After reading through the source of the `Menu` plugin and `Page` class, it looks like it only supports exact route matches by name and setting the `controller` option doesn't work.

Just to test, we added the section `Navigation` to the global `Navigation` as would be done in a standard configuration and the desired results are shown where the global item is always active in all routes in the section.

**Is there any way to make this work with the current configuration? If not, what would you suggest to make the structure so that it can work?**

Answer (score 0):

We have had success with using something like this in the global `Navigation` service factory:

```
$event = $serviceLocator->get('Application')->getMvcEvent();
$matched_route = $event->getRouteMatch()->getMatchedRouteName();
$route_section = explode('/',$matched_route)[0];
```

And then when defining the pages:

```
array(
    array(
        'type' => 'mvc',
        'label' => 'Section 1',
        'route' => 'section1',
        'active' => ($route_section === 'section1')
    ),
    // ... etc
)
```

## Caveat...

This solution can be limiting. This prevents us from having cross-section URLs. Sections cannot contain links for routes in another section without it changing the global navigation active item. Hopefully this will not be a problem for us.